# Hypothesis testing of a binomial variable

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

There's this problem I'm trying to solve and I can't wrap my head around it;

Let X be a binomial variable. The number $x_k$ of times we observed $k$ successes in 96 repetitions of the experiment is given by this table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{k} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\text{$x_k$} & 5 & 22 & 35 & 28 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Should we accept with $\alpha = 0.10$ the hypothesis $H_0$ that $X\sim Bin(4,\frac{1}{2})$

From what I understand, what we're testing is

$$H_0: p=\frac{1}{2}    \space \space \space H_1: p \neq \frac{1}{2} \space\space\space when \space n=4$$

But I can't find what value I should test it with... Just from looking at the data it looks about right but... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems you are on the right path. You need to come up with a test statistic, devise a test (how to reject based on that statistic), and then find the (approximate) distribution of that statistic under the null to be able to satisfy the size constraint (i.e., set the right threshold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_i \sim \text{Bin}(m,p)$ iid over $i=1,\dots,n$ under the null. The likelihood of the model is 
$$\propto \prod_{i=1}^n p^{Y_i}(1-p)^{m-Y_i} = [p/(1-p)]^{\sum_i Y_i}(1-p)^m$$
so rejecting based on $\sum_i Y_i$ would be the most powerful test for one-sided alternatives. Generally, this suggests that basing any test on $T = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is a good idea.

The data you are given is $x_k = \sum_{i=1}^n 1\{Y_i = k\}$ (what is the relation between these and $T$?)

Under the null, we can reject based on $|T - E[T]|$ being large. By CLT (under the null),
$$
T' := \frac{ T - E[T]} {\sqrt{\text{var}(T)}}
$$
is approximately normally distributed (when $mn$ is large). You can use this to approximately set the threshold $\tau$ such that $P_{H_0}( |T'| \ge \tau) \approx \alpha$.